# Assign values to a column based on Min and Max of a particular group

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby, apply

I have 3 fields Cust_ID, Acc_No and Product like the table below
[image]

I need to add a column 'Type' based on 'Product' value for each Cust_ID. If all the 'Product' values for a customer lie between range 'a' to 'm' or 'n' to 'z' then it should be labeled as 'Single' else 'Multiple' like in the below table
[image]

I am trying to group by 'Cust_ID' and compare min and max value of 'Product' with range '<=m' and '>=n' but not able to implement it successfully. Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't use images to show code. Copy and paste the code in your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.groupby.transform` + [`Series.between`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html#pandas-series-between):

```py
df["Type"] = df.groupby("Cust_ID")["Product"].transform(
    lambda x: np.where(
        x.between("a", "m").all() | x.between("n", "z").all(),
        "Single",
        "Multiple",
    )
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Cust_ID  Acc_No Product      Type
0        1     111       a    Single
1        1     112       b    Single
2        1     113       c    Single
3        2     221       a  Multiple
4        2     222       x  Multiple
5        2     223       y  Multiple
6        3     331       z    Single
7        3     332       x    Single
```